# What is the meaning of Sub_tm in this context?

Tags: finite-automata, undecidability

Im working on a problem for a homework assignment in finite automata, but I'm having trouble conceptually grasping the problem in the first place.

Prove that the following is undecidable:
$SUB_{TM} = \{\langle M_1,M_2 \rangle \mid L(M_1) \subseteq L(M_2)\}$

I'm not sure what kind of Turing machine $SUB_{TM}$ is even describing. Can anyone help me conceptually understand this problem or possibly give me any hints? I would of course cite this post in my homework submission. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$SUB_{TM}$ is the **problem** (language) of deciding whether for two given turing machines $M_1$ and $M_2$, we have that $L(M_1)\subseteq L(M_2)$.

Your task is to show that this language is undecidable - there is no turing machine that decides $SUB_{TM}$.

Comment: As silly as the question this was, this answer was actually really helpful. I understand the basic definition format in most contexts but was thrown off for a couple of typos in the early version of the assignment and thought it was a turning machine I was supposed to be familiar with. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I can help! The question was not silly at all ;)